# Join SQL Statements optimization

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 Tables:

**Customer**

```
ID
Customer_ID
Name
Sir_Name
Phone
Email
```

and

**Table Invoice**

```
Manager_Name
Manaer_First_Name
Customer_ID1
Customer_ID2
Customer_ID3
```

There is only one `Customer.Customer_ID` for each Customer or a Customer has no Customer_ID

In **Invoice.Customer_ID1** i have the same **Customer_ID.Customer_ID** several times.

I Like to get all Records in `Customer Table Join Invoice Table` - check if the `Customer_ID = Customer_ID1` if not check in `Customer_ID = Customer_ID2 Or Customer_ID = Customer_ID2`

If customer_ID is found in one of rows stop the search.

Comment: please provide example

Comment: You need COALESCE() (and JOIN the customer table three times)

Comment: SQL is a _declarative_ language, meaning you tell the system what results you want and it decides the best way to get the data.  So saying "If customer_ID is found in one of rows stop the search" is not appropriate for SQL since it will determine _how_ to get the data.  So you should be writing a query that focuses on what you want, not how to get it.

Comment: When asking SQL questions, you should always tag the DBMS used. As SQL dialects differ, a solution for one DBMS may not be appropriate for another.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to write the query is:

```
select . . .
from customer c join
     invoice i
     on c.customer_id = coalesce(i.customer_id1, i.customer_id2, i.customer_id3);
```

This should be able to take advantage of an index on `customer(customer_id)`.  If this is not efficient, then another alternative is `left join`:

```
select . . ., coalesce(c1.col1, c2.col1, c3.col1) as col1, . . .
from invoice i left join
     customer c1
     on c1.customer_id = i.customer_id1 left join
     customer c2
     on c2.customer_id = i.customer_id2 left join
     customer c3
     on c3.customer_id = i.customer_id3;
```

The `left join` *can* take advantage of an index on `customer(customer_id)`.  You need to use `coalesce()` in the `select` to choose the field from the right table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    *
from [Table Invoice] A
JOIN [Customer] B
    ON B.Customer_ID = A.Customer_ID1 OR (B.Customer_ID <> A.Customer_ID1 AND B.Customer_ID = A.Customer_ID2) OR (B.Customer_ID = A.Customer_ID3 AND B.Customer_ID <> A.Customer_ID2 AND B.Customer_ID <> A.Customer_ID1)
```

this would return you all the Invoices for all of the Customers. In case you need Invoices just for one customer - add

```
WHERE B.Customer_ID = @YourCustomerID
```

statement. If you need only one, first invoice, add 'TOP 1' to select statement:

```
SELECT TOP 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Could a inner join on or clause

```
 select Customer.*, Invocie.*
 from Customer
 inner join Invoice on ( Customer.Customer_ID = Invoce.Customer_ID1
   OR Customer.Customer_ID = Invoce.Customer_ID2 
   OR Customer.Customer_ID = Invoce.Customer_ID3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand your request: You want all customers that have at least one entry in the invoice table. But per customer you want the "best" invoice record only; with ID1 match better than ID2 match and ID2 match better than ID3 match.

So join the tables to get *all* matches and then rank your matches with `row_number` giving the best matching record #1. Then only keep those rows ranked #1.

```
select *
from
(
  select 
    c.*, 
    i.*,
    row_number() over 
    (
      partition by c.customer_id order by 
        case c.customer_id 
          when i.customer_id1 then 1
          when i.customer_id2 then 2
          when i.customer_id3 then 3
        end
    ) as rn
  from customer c
  join invoice i on c.customer_id in (i.customer_id1, i.customer_id2, i.customer_id3)
)
where rn = 1;
```